# How to flow text using CSS shape-outside with a triangle?

Tags: html, css

```css
.triangle {
  width: 40%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}

.text {}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nobis commune pertinax ei quo, pri laudem putant instructior in. Per molestiae evertitur ut, voluptua volutpat in sit. Ad viderer scaevola lucilius eos. Ea sed vulputate dissentias neglegentur. At eam cibo nostrum efficiendi.
  </p>
</div>
```

I have a project where I'm trying to flow text along a triangle using shape-outside. However, I can't seem to make the text stay to left and flow at an angle with the triangle.

Here it is with the float left. [Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3u10rcak/24/)

Anything I've tried to get the text to stay on the left ignores the shape-outside.

Is there a way to do this or a better approach?

This is what I want it to look like:
[Image of triangle with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7ekS.jpg)

Comment: `shape-outside` is only supported in WebKit browsers. It is not supported in IE, Edge or Firefox. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make the `width:100%` and use `float:right` instead of left:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nobis commune pertinax ei quo, pri laudem putant instructior in. Per molestiae evertitur ut, voluptua volutpat in sit. Ad viderer scaevola lucilius eos. Ea sed vulputate dissentias neglegentur. At eam cibo nostrum efficiendi. in. Per molestiae evertitur ut, voluptua volutpat in sit. Ad viderer scaevola lucilius eos. Ea sed vulputate dissentias neglegentur. At eam cibo nostrum efficiendi. in. Per molestiae evertitur ut, voluptua volutpat in sit. Ad viderer scaevola lucilius eos. Ea sed vulputate dissentias neglegentur. At eam cibo nostrum efficiendi.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See me.  Not 100% sure what your "wrap around" means but perhaps this will get you started.  Note the `float:left`. Note I changed the angle (width) to provide emphasis on the wrap.

```css
.triangle {
float:left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0 100%,100% 100%  );
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100% , 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100% , 100% 100%);
}

.text {}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
</div>
<div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nobis commune pertinax ei quo, pri laudem putant instructior in. Per molestiae evertitur ut, voluptua volutpat in sit. Ad viderer scaevola lucilius eos. Ea sed vulputate dissentias neglegentur. At eam cibo nostrum efficiendi.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nobis commune pertinax ei quo, pri laudem putant instructior in. Per molestiae evertitur ut, voluptua volutpat in sit. Ad viderer scaevola lucilius eos. Ea sed vulputate dissentias neglegentur. At eam cibo nostrum efficiendi.
</div>
```

Comment: This floats to the right and I'm trying to get the angle of the triangle on the left.. Thanks for the reply. I'm going to add an image to my question for clarification.

Comment: I went with YOUR triangle.  Change that then float:left.

Comment: I cannot vouch for the browser support of this, might not work on some.

Comment: I added an image in my question to show what I'm attempting to do. For now I'm ok with just using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It might be just to float right?

```css
.triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}

.text {}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nobis commune pertinax ei quo, pri laudem putant instructior in. Per molestiae evertitur ut, voluptua volutpat in sit. Ad viderer scaevola lucilius eos. Ea sed vulputate dissentias neglegentur. At eam cibo nostrum efficiendi.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you think there's a way to have it float right and have the tip of the left side of the triangle extend to the left edge of the screen?

Comment: Just change the width of the object, see how I did that.