# How to build a diagonal hero section?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to find the best way to build a layout for a hero section on a webpage, which is half content and half an image, divided with a diagonal line; something like this:

[image]

I've been reading about using SVG, `clip-path` and things like that but I'm not really sure how to use them; or if those would be easy to handle with responsive design, since basically I need the image to take that shape, since it is provided by the user so it's not like I can just insert an image already clipped like that.

The basic structure I'm thinking of is something like:

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="hero-image">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="hero-content">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum non id saepe quae praesentium exercitationem omnis ratione nulla optio, tempore repellendus maxime veritatis molestiae. Laudantium quisquam illum atque excepturi expedita.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can just divide the screen at 50% width, but I need to actually separate both parts like the image above, any ideas or directions?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49688507/8620333

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55034678/8620333

Comment: Thank you, will check both questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step would be to generate a clipping shape for the image, i used https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/, it lets your generate custom shapes.

Created a right angled triangle to set the shape of the `<div>` which will have the image set as its background.

`.hero-image{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080');
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}`

```css
.hero-container{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.hero-image{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080');
  background-position: center;
  
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
.hero-text{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:10%;
}
h1{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container">
  <div class="hero-image">
  </div>
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>This is some text for the placeholder</p>
    <button>click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, yeah, looks really good, just need to make sure there's no horizontal scrolling, but this is amazing, thank you... Can you add a bit of explanation to what you did?

Comment: @IvanS95 so you don't want the text to follow the shape? if it's the case, then it's easier that the quesition I linked (a simple background can do it

Comment: @IvanS95, there's this nice site that lets you generate custom shapes, https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/, i'll add more description to the answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif What do you mean? I do need the content to just stick to half of the screen, the half that does not have the background image

Comment: @IvanS95 I thought (like the examples I shared) you want the text to fit the triangular shape, probably check the example I shared and you will understand what I meant ... but it seems you don't want this

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is what I'm trying to build https://imgur.com/a/pSlogqd maybe it clears it up

Comment: @TemaniAfif That looks exactly like what I need, will try it, thank you!